# Real time clock for PIC16LF1902/03

Tags: electrical-engineering, embedded-systems

I'm finding difficult in implementing real time clock for pic16lf1902, wherein their are no serial protocols for communicating/interfacing with builtin LCD display. Is their a convenient way to solve the problem? For example using I2C software functions with DS1309 for LCD disply as used for PIC18 microcontrollers.

Comment: Welcome to Engineering SE. I am not too familiar with DS1309, is this a typo. There is DS1307 which is a RTC  that uses I2C. Since PIC16LF1902 doesn't have a serial communication, consider I2C bit bang implementation. Here is a link [I2C driver using bit bang](http://www.embeddedrelated.com/showcode/334.php)

Comment: Also check out this link [20x4 lcd with DS1307 rtc interface with AT89c51](http://www.engineersgarage.com/forums/8051/20x4-lcd-ds1307-rtc-interface-at89c51) this might help you too.

Comment: @MahendraGunawardena If this is the case then I have to interface the LCD drive with I2C right! Anyway I will try it out.

Comment: Are you trying to interface a RTC that communicates via I2C with a PIC16LF1902.

Comment: @MahendraGunawardena Yes, I'm trying to implement RTC using PIC16lf1902. I tried with pic16f887, it worked but I'm bit confused with 16lf1902 as it has come with LCD driver and not getting which protocol to use.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm finding difficult in implementing real time clock for pic16lf1902

This PIC, as most 8 bit PICs, can drive a 32786 Hz low power "watch" crystal directly.  This peripheral is called the *Timer 1 oscillator* because it directly drives timer 1.  Timer 1 and its oscillator can run during sleep, then cause the processor to wake periodically, like every second.

You use the 1 second periodic wakeup to drive the real time clock logic.  Most of the time, you just increment the seconds counter and go back to sleep.  Since the processor is only run a few µs every second and sleeping the rest of the time, the average current draw is very low and appropriate for a real time clock.

The maximum sleep current is 1 µA at 1.8 V and up to 85°C, with it usually being much less than that.

> wherein their are no serial protocols for communicating/interfacing with builtin LCD display

Huh?  What?  It doesn't come with a sensor for measuring the ripeness of tomatoes either, but neither has anything to do with the real time clock you are asking about.

And no, this PIC doesn't have a built-in LCD.  None of them do.  By what hallucination do you imagine a liquid crystal somehow "integrated" onto a silicon chip?

The basic problem appears to be that you don't understand what microcontrollers are.  Go back and learn some basics, and also learn to formulate and present questions clearly.